# MySQL: Find Records Without a Match (JOIN/IS NULL)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a query for these simplified MySQL tables:

```
==campaigns==  
id  
content  

==lists==  
id  
name  

==subscriptions==  
id  
list_id   
subscriber_id  

==events==  
id  
campaign_id
list_id
subscription_id

==triggers==
id
campaign_id
list_id
time_to_send
```

I want to find the subscription_id for all subscriptions without a corresponding event for a certain campaign_id.

This query returns all subscriptions without an event:

`SELECT *
FROM subscriptions AS s
LEFT JOIN events AS e
ON s.id = e.subscription_id
WHERE e.subscription_id IS NULL`

But, I want to return all subscriptions either **without an event for a particular campaign** or **without an event for a particular trigger**.

How would I do this?

Comment: SELECT * FROM subscriptions AS s LEFT JOIN events AS e ON s.id = e.subscription_id INNER JOIN campaigns ON e.campaign_id = campaigns.id WHERE (e.subscription_id IS NULL) AND (campaigns.id = ID) surely..?

Comment: Sorry, what? The event holds the campaign. How can you have a subscription _without_ an event but _with_ a campagin?

Comment: You can have multiple campaigns that are sent under a certain subscription. A subscription might be sent a campaign (#1) immediately, but have a different campaign (#2) queued to be sent two days from now. So, there could be an entry in the events table that we sent campaign #1, but we want to know if this subscription has ever been sent campaign #2 specifically.

Answer (score 0):

> But, I want to return all subscriptions without an event for a particular campaign

Since the relationship between subscriptions and campaigns is *defined* by events this is impossible.

> So, there could be an entry in the events table that we sent campaign #1, but we want to know if this subscription has ever been sent campaign #2 specifically

If you want to identify subscriptions which are associated with campaign #1 but not campaign #2 then that's a *completely* different question....

```
SELECT s.*
FROM subscriptions s
INNER JOIN events e
  ON s.id=e.subscription_id
INNER JOIN campaigns c
  ON e.campaign_id=c.id
WHERE c.content='campaign #1'
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM events e2
   INNER JOIN capaigns c2
     ON e2.campaign_id=c2.id
   WHERE c2.content='campaign #2'
   AND e2.subscription_id=e.subscription_id
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just modified the question to include the `triggers` table. This table has the rules for which list gets sent a campaign at a certain time. What if I modify the events table to have a trigger_id for each event? Then, when a campaign is sent, it is logged in events that "this trigger" (corresponding to a certain list and campaign) created "this event"? Could I do a query that says "find all subscription_ids without an event for "this trigger" in the events table?